# Preventing SelectedIndexChanged() method being called when we call TabPages.Clear()

Tags: c#, winforms

C# WinForms: When I call Clear() method of a TabPages:

```
tabControl.TabPages.Clear();
```

it is also firing SelectedIndexChanged event

```
tabControl_SelectedIndexChanged
```

. But I don't want that. Is there a formal or even a hackish way to prevent this being called when I call Clear()? I still want it to be called whenever the user clicks on a tab, but I just don't want it to automatically get called when somewhere else I am calling the Clear() method.

Thank you.

Comment: Quick fix: Unhook the eventhandler, Clear the tab pages, Hook the eventhandler againt.

Comment: Thanks. You can post it as answer. It worked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the comment I made you could make it an Extension Method:

```
public static void ClearAllTabPages(this TabControl tc, EventHandler eh)
{
  tc.SelectedIndexChanged -= eh;
  tc.TabPages.Clear();
  tc.SelectedIndexChanged += eh;
}
```

Now you don't need to remember to unhook and rehook the event handler in every place you would like to clear the TabPages at. You just call:

```
tabControl.ClearAllTabPages(tabControl_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

**Note:**
I havn't tried this code but it should work.

Comment: It has issue that if there is an error in  < tc.TabPages.Clear(); > then we will loose our event handler .

Comment: @Dhananjay: Of course one should always implement proper error handling. On Stack Overflow we usually omit error handling for clarity.

Comment: true , but the seriousness of the impact is more so wanted to add that point.

Comment: `Clear` will never fail or throw so error checking is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

As Sani commented, this is a simple work around:

```
tabControl.SelectedIndexChanged -= tabControl_SelectedIndexChanged;
tabControl.TabPages.Clear();
tabControl.SelectedIndexChanged += tabControl_SelectedIndexChanged;
```

Comment: It has issue that if there is an error in  < tc.TabPages.Clear(); > then we will loose our event handler .